# Export typescript vuejs component from lib correctly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

Trying to create a vuejs lib including `vue-notifications` and `vue-router` I have the following `index.ts`:

```js
import MyComponent1 from './components/MyComponent1.vue';
import MyComponent2 from './components/MyComponent2.vue';

export default {
    install(Vue: any, options:any){
        Vue.component('MyComponent1', MyComponent1);
        Vue.component('MyComponent2', MyComponent2);
    }
}
```

Additionally I have the following `vue-shims.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '*.vue'{
    import Vue from  'vue';
    export default Vue;
}
```

The components uses internally `this.$router` and `this.$notify`. The components from the lib-consuming project should also use this ones.

With the stated `vue-shims.d.ts` I can build the lib without errors but get in my main project the errors `this.$notify does not exist on type ...`.

How do I need to change the lib that this works?

I already tried to change the shims-file to

```js
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Vue from 'vue'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $router: Router
  }
}
```

But then the build couldn't find the components anymore.

Comment: Basically the steps are: 1. compile your library down to javascript 2. declare `.d.ts` files and exposes them from the `package.json` so that TS clients can use your types. 3. Add a peer-dependency to `vue-router` to notify the client he needs this library.